# Delete rows in which column A contains values in column A of Sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I'm traiting an 40M Excel file, I'm thinking of doing some deletes.

For example, I have the data in Sheet 1, and the primary key which I want to delete in sheet2.

Sheet 1

```
Column A | Column B | ...
0047     |  a       | ...
0048     |  b       | ...
0051     |  c       | ...
```

Sheet 2

```
 Column A
 0047
 0051
```

Would you please tell me how do write a VBA script which delete line 0047 and 0051 in Sheet 1?
I'm new to VBA scripting.

Comment: `I need a macro...` - what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello simoco, I've try to do it without macro, but it's more efficient in macro as I've a 'list-of-delete'. Sorry to be rude

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. _Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results_. See also: [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the code below. Loops through the rows until you find the values you are after using the line below you can delete rows:

```
Rows(i - j).Delete
```

Complete code:

```
Sub main()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
j = 0
For i = 2 To 1000
    If (Cells(i - j, 1) = "0047") Or (Cells(i - j, 1) = "0051") Then
        Rows(i - j).Delete
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, VBA Programmer. Thanks for your help. While the 0047 or 0051 is a exemple, I have a 'list-of-delete' in sheet2 Column A. How can I do? Thanks

Comment: You could add another loop to check for the values to delete

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain your code. If you do explain this code (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!

Comment: sorry about that, thought it was straight forward, I'll add an explanation to it